# Array of Structures or Structure of Arrays performance

Tags: opengl

I'm using a MacMini '11 with the AMD Radeon HD 6630M.  I'm drawing a mesh using a structure of arrays and all is well: 60 fps (using CVDisplayLink).  I use a shader with built-in attributes.  Life is good. I'm switching to using an array of structures (interleaved), because I understand that this is preferred with "modern" GPUs.  The attributes are defined in the shader. The mesh is drawn beautifully. But when I do this, the frame rate drops about 33% (to 40 fps). And there are multiple copies of those calls. Using Instruments:Time Profiler, I get the following comparisons:

```
Using structure of arrays (60 fps)
Running Time    Self    Symbol Name
3.0ms    0.0%   3.0 0x21b76c4           ATIRadeonX3000GLDriver
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0  gldUpdateDispatch  ATIRadeonX3000GLDriver
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0    gleDoDrawDispatchCore        GLEngine
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0     glDrawElements_ACC_Exec GLEngine
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0      glDrawElements     libGL.dylib
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0       -[Mesh draw]      me

Using array of structures (40 fps)
Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
393.0ms    7.4% 393.0   0x86f6695               ?
393.0ms    7.4% 0.0  gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore   GLEngine
393.0ms    7.4% 0.0    glDrawElements_IMM_Exec      GLEngine
393.0ms    7.4% 0.0     glDrawElements          libGL.dylib
393.0ms    7.4% 0.0     -[Mesh draw]            me
```

It looks like libGL is making a decision to go in different directions, and the array of structures looks like the X3000 driver isn't getting called.  Is it executing in the Apple software emulator?  Should I just stay with structure of arrays?  Has anyone seen anything like this?

---

The code for attributes is from an Apple example and is used throughout my app (at least 10 other areas) with no performance hit in those areas.  This is from the slow version.  As I mentioned, I'm using built-in attributes in the fast version since the data is not interleaved. The rendering is spot on, just slow.

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
//  Step 5 - Bind each of the vertex shader's attributes to the programs
[self.meshShader addAttribute:@"inPosition"];
[self.meshShader addAttribute:@"inNormal"];
[self.meshShader addAttribute:@"inTexCoord"];

//  Step 6 - Link the program
if([[self meshShader] linkShader] == 0){
    self.posAttribute = [meshShader attributeIndex:@"inPosition"];
    self.normAttribute = [meshShader attributeIndex:@"inNormal"];   
    self.texCoordAttribute = [meshShader attributeIndex:@"inTexCoord"]; 

...


- (void) addAttribute:(NSString *)attributeName
{
    if ([attributes containsObject:attributeName] == NO){
        [attributes addObject:attributeName];
        glBindAttribLocation(program, [attributes indexOfObject:attributeName],     
        [attributeName UTF8String]);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
After further investigation:
1) I'm using dhpoWare's modelObj loader (modified) and since it uses interleaved array of structures, it also acts like my array of structures performance-wise - just not as bit a hit.  I may be interpreting Instruments incorrectly.  The modelObj code does call glDrawElements_IMM_Exec, it also in a roundabout way calls gleDoDrawDispatchCore.  I'm not sure if it is just accumulating a bunch of calls at glDrawElements_IMM_Exec and then blasting them out via gleDoDrawDispatchCore.  Dunno.
2) I think Instruments has issues since it shows the GLEngine calling one of my unused internal 3ds object methods which has no external hooks.  I double checked by setting an Xcode breakpoint there and it never tripped.  I don't do 3DS any more.

I guess I'll keep looking around and perhaps stumble on an answer.  If someone would give me an opinion on whether an array of structures is the way to go, it would be appreciated.

SOLUTION:
I added a VBO to the front end of this and all is well.  The original code came from the OpenGL ES 2.0 Guide and the addition of the VBO fixes my issue.  Frame rate at 60, 1 ms driver calls.  Here is the code:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoName);
glBindVertexArray(vaoName);

//  new - create VBO
glGenBuffers(1, &vboName);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboName);

//  Allocate and load position data into the VBO
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(struct vertexAttribs) * self.numVertices,                                             
                   vertexAttribData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//  end of new

NSUInteger  vtxStride = sizeof(struct vertexAttribs);
//GLfloat   *vtxBuf = (GLfloat *)vertexAttribData;    // no longer use this
GLfloat *vtxBuf = (GLfloat *)NULL;                // use this instead

glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.posAttribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.posAttribute, VERTEX_POS_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                        vtxStride, vtxBuf);
vtxBuf += VERTEX_POS_SIZE;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.normAttribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.normAttribute, VERTEX_NORM_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                        vtxStride, vtxBuf);
vtxBuf += VERTEX_NORM_SIZE;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.texCoordAttribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.texCoordAttribute, VERTEX_TEX_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                        vtxStride, vtxBuf);
...
```

Comment: Could you post the code that's setting up the attribute arrays? Both the fast and slow versions?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that others know this problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Struct of Arrays for achieving unit-stride access in memory is the rule of thumb. It apply not only for GPU but also for CPUS and Co-processors like Intel Xeon Phi.

In your case, I don't believe this portion of code is being sent to GPU, instead the loss of performance is due to non unit-stride memory access (CPU to/from Memory).